# Weird scrolling issues on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, web

I'm running out of ideas as to what's going on. I find it hard to explain so to start of here are a couple GIFs:

- https://i.gyazo.com/9b501a93641db8f10320bc360393541f.mp4
- https://i.gyazo.com/9b9f5a0ef654d7e51ad318b61663d897.mp4

I tried removing every script and it didn't work, I also tried removing every CSS and it also didn't work, and lastly I tried removing both, and it still didn't work. What the heck? This is the homepage section of the website and it only happens here. Ugh. Any ideas?

EDIT: I forgot to mention something very important, it only happens after you've visited the page, not before. The first load is always alright, but if you go to another part of the website then go back, this happens.

EDIT #2: It appears to be related to how the browser stores the scrollbar position and then "remembers" it after you refresh and it places you there. There is no problem if I reload the page anywhere but at the top. If I try to reload at the top, instead of staying there, it tries to go to the place prior to where it was, and it sort of jumps between the two figuring out where to go, I just don't know what's going on at this point.

Comment: Hi, it's very difficult to debug unless we can tinker with it. Give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) a read, and see if you can't replicate the issue with demonstrable code.

Comment: Thanks Frish, I'll build a better example with all the html and javascript that's included in the page.